# Finding Normal to a given point in ECEF coordinates

Tags: remote-sensing, radar

I have a point of reference called Ground Reference Point (GRP) given in Earth Centred Earth Fixed (ECEF) coordinates as given below:

(1.4892e+6, 6.1102e+6, 1.0637e+6) (all distances in meters)

I want to find a normal to the earth ellipsoid at the above mentioned GRP again in ECEF coordinates. What is the process to calculate it?

Answer (score 1):

Convert your ECEF coordinates into latitude, longitude, and height.
There are several packages that will do this for you.  One is
[GeographicLib](http://geographiclib.sf.net), which has a utility [CartConvert](http://geographiclib.sf.net/html/CartConvert.1.html), which you
would invoke with

```
$ echo 1.4892e+6 6.1102e+6 1.0637e+6 | CartConvert -r
->
9.663343910567409 76.302710255343555 839.627563829778
```

(by default, CartConverts uses the WGS84 ellipsoid).
The normal to the ellipsoid is [cos(φ) cos(λ), cos(φ)
sin(λ), sin(φ)] with φ = 9.66334° and
λ = 76.30271° or [0.23343, 0.95777, 0.16786].